How to return the same value using for loop and mysql query in Python
I have a code with some variables and I need to find the same data from my mysql database.
from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

horses = "Love Your Work (IRE)"
terrain = "Standard"
courses = "Doncaster"
distances = "1m"
pos1 = "1"
pos2 = "2"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="horseracinguk"
)

#engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:new_password@localhost/mydatabase")
engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/mydbname?')


mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
   if horses == row["horse"]:
     if ((terrain == row["going"]) and (pos1 == row["pos"])):   
        pointsgoing1 = 2

        horse = row["horse"]
        terrain = row["going"]
        course = row["course"]
        distance = row["dist"]
        position = row["pos"]
        print(horse, terrain, course, distance, position, pointsgoing1)

I have a problem with this code, because when I am trying to find the same "terrain" variable (for example, "Standard"), my for loop returns not just rows with the word "Standard", but also rows with this word inside that column (example: "Standard to Fast", "Standard to Slow"), but I'd like to get just the row with the exact word "Standard".
Any suggestion, please?
Thanks

Rename your variable "terrain" at beginning to "terrains" or something, because you are changing it in the loop.

Ok, it's working. Is it possible to stop the loop when it match the conditions? Thanks

if condition: break

Please closed the ticket @marcellogabrielli if it's resolved

@ArtBindu sorry, but how can I do it, please?
